# ListFragment inside viewPager does not display data in some pages and works well in some pages

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment that fetches json data from the internet and displays in a listView.And i reuse this fragment in a viewPager.It loads data and displays in first two pages but keeps loading in the third page.Most pages work but some pages in between does not work.What i dont understand is that i use same fragment across all pages but does not work in some pages.I reuse the same fragment by creating a newInstance and passing the url to fetch data from.If i provide more code the viewers get overwhelmed so i guess this is enough.Are there any rules that i should follow while fetching and display list in ListFragments.Am i doing something wrong?

My adapter:

```
public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                Log.d("Adapter","Case 0 called");
                return new LisViewFragment2();

            case 1:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=al-jazeera-english&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 2:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=associated-press&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 3:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 4:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=cnn&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 5:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=google-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 6:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=independent&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 7:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=metro&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 8:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=mirror&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 9:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=newsweek&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 10:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=new-york-magazine&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 11:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=reddit-r-all&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 12:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=reuters&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 13:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-guardian-uk&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 14:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-hindu&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 15:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-times-of-india&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 16:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-new-york-times&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            case 17:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-telegraph&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");

            default:
                return ListViewFragment.newInstance("https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=usa-today&sortBy=top&apiKey=my_key");


        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 19;
    }


}
```

Comment: try your code by Using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

override **getItemPosition** and return POSITION_NONE

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    return POSITION_NONE;
}
```